# Drawing Colored Geometry in OpenGL using SDL

Tags: opengl, sdl

First off, I will confess I have asked the same question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378472/sdl2-opengl-colored-geometry), but I think this forum might be a better fit.

I am trying to combine 2 things using SDL:

1. Draw a **webcam** feed via an SDL_Surface (from OpenCV).
2. Draw some plain **colored geometry** on top, using OpenGL.

The problem I have is that—I think—the geometry is textured by the screen texture that I draw the webcam feed in, even if I call `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` right before drawing the quad. See the screenshot below, the square in the top-left is supposed to be *white*, but it seems to have the color of the **bottom-right** texel.

[image: Blue Square should be White]

The code in my `Display` function is as follows:

```
// screen_surface_ contains a frame from the camera
SDL_UpdateTexture(screen_texture_, NULL, screen_surface_->pixels, screen_surface_->pitch);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer_);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer_, screen_texture_, NULL, NULL);

glLoadIdentity();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
  glVertex3f( 10.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f ); /* Top Left */
  glVertex3f( 50.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f ); /* Top Right */
  glVertex3f( 50.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f ); /* Bottom Right */
  glVertex3f( 10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f ); /* Bottom Left */
glEnd( );

glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer_);
```

[You can view all the code of relevant functions here.](https://gist.github.com/noio/8730246)

I got a blanket answer saying "Don't mix SDL and OpenGL draw code"; as addressed in this [bug report](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138). But that would mean I'm simply stuck waiting for that bug to be fixed, so I'm still looking for a way to disable texturing after `SDL_RenderCopy` has been called.

**Edit:** I've confirmed that it's indeed still using the `screen_texture_`. Setting the `texCoord` to values between 0-100 shows a part of the webcam feed. (I tried 0-1 first but then I read that texCoords are different for rectangular images).

Comment: Please note that this isn't a forum. Please see the [about] page.

Comment: Also, the OpenGL that you are using is old OpenGL. All but one of the functions you called are deprecated. I am not sure if that is the cause of the problem, but you should still upgrade to modern OpenGL.

Comment: s/forum/site/ ;) Could you point me to the newer functions I'm supposed to use? I copied this code from an "SDL + OpenGL" example.

Comment: I can't give you a list of all of them as almost everything changed in modern OpenGL. But I can link you to a tutorial that uses modern OpenGL: [arcsynthesis](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/)

Comment: @AidanMueller, thanks. It took me a whole day to figure out how to correctly use VBOs; additionally, I migrated to SFML because it messes a little less with the OpenGL state.

Comment: I believe some parts of SFML still use legacy OpenGL (SFML runs on OpenGL in the backgound), so it seemed to give me problems when trying to run certain functions (I think I may have done a bad job of compiling GLEW though). If you happen to have issues, try using SDL instead. Otherwise you can keep using SFML.

Comment: Thanks :) the CreateContext solved my original problem though; I just had to wait to be able to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[(Crosspost from stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21482196/224949)

I have fixed the problem by simply adding

```
glcontext_ = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window_);
```

to the `SDL_Init` code. I think all my calls to openGL functions (like `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` were applied to the wrong context. Explicitly creating a context from SDL sets the right context to be active, I'm guessing.

**Something else to look out for**: when using *textured* geometry after using `SDL_RenderCopy`; I had to make sure to reset

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
```

before calling `glTexImage2d`, because it uses

> GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH if it is greater than 0, the width argument to the pixel routine otherwise

(from the [OpenGL docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml))